# Converting a php array to SQL array

Tags: php, sql, mysql, adodb

I want something like the following:

```
$arrayOfValues = array(1,2,3,4);
$sqlArray = mysql_convertToSqlArray($arrayOfValues);
```

which then will return what in SQL would be:

```
(1,2,3,4)
```

but in php would be the string "(1,2,3,4)"

Comment: Note that SQL doesn't have arrays. Some expressions take what's called an expression list, but this is a purely syntactical object and not a type. When it comes to SQL, thinking in terms of lists or arrays will trip you up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no builtin function specifically for creating SQL arrays, but you could just [`join`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) the array and wrap it in parentheses:

```
$arrayOfValues = array(1,2,3,4);
$sqlArray = '(' . join(',', $arrayOfValues) . ')';
```

See this in action at http://www.ideone.com/KYApN.

Comment: Anybody have any experience with ideone.com? At first glance it looks like jsfiddle for php...which would be bloody awesome.

Comment: @treeface it's jsfiddle for all kinds of languages. :)

Comment: This is quite useful. However, if anyone wants to convert array with characters in it, you can do this: ```"('" . join("','", $arrayOfValues) . "')";```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php.
This function can be used as following: `$sqlArray = "(" . implode(",", $arrayOfValues) . ")";`

**[Edit]**
Ps: join is an alias of implode.